# Erro em projeto: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Estou fazendo um console com javascript porém tenho tido problemas para descobrir a origem do erro. Já revisei o código várias vezes e não consegui descobrir o que há de errado. Qualquer ajuda é apreciada.

```js
var logStack = 0;
var showTime = false;
var currDate = new Date();
var i = 0;
var tempStr = "temp";

function getLogStr(var lineNum) {
 if(lineNum <= 10 & lineNum > 0) {
  return document.getELementById("line" + lineNum);
 } else {
  tempSTr = "Invalid line!";
  return tempStr;
 }
}

function setLogStr(var newLog, var line) {
 if(line <= 10 & line > 0) {
 document.getELementById("line" + line).innerHTML = newLog;
 } else {
  console.log("Invalid line!");
 }
}

function shiftLog(var line10) {

if(logStack == 10) {
 for(i = 1;i <= 10;i++) {
  setLogStr(i,getLogStr(i + 1));
 }
 setLogStr(10,line10);

} else {
 console.log("There are free lines!");
}
}



function logOnConsole(var newLog) {
currDate = Date();
 if(logStack == 10) {
  shiftLog(new Date().getHours());
 } else {
  setLogStr(newLog, logSTack + 1);
  logStack++;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Ice Console</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="line1"></div>
<br />
<div id="line2"></div>
<br />
<div id="line3"></div>
<br />
<div id="line4"></div>
<br />
<div id="line5"></div>
<br />
<div id="line6"></div>
<br />
<div id="line7"></div>
<br />
<div id="line8"></div>
<br />
<div id="line9"></div>
<br />
<div id="line10"></div>
<br />
<input type="text" id="console" />
<input type="button" value="Run" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retira todos os `var` dos argumentos das funções, isso é sintaxe errada em JavaScript.

Ou seja: muda `function getLogStr(var lineNum) {` para `function getLogStr(lineNum) {`.

Essas variáveis como `lineNum` são declaradas pela função e ficam só disponíveis dentro da função (ou seja: ficam limitadas ao escopo da função).

Comment: Obrigado, faz tempo que eu não programo em javascript e estava mais acostumado com Java, desse jeito acabei não me tocando.